# stack 2 images together in numpy

Tags: python, image, numpy, stack

from below codw when 1 image is passed the shape i get is (1,3,640,640).

```
def shape(im1):
    image_src = Image.open(im1)
    print('Loaded Image Info : ',image_src.format, image_src.size, image_src.mode) # size order : width*height

    # Resize to img_size_w, img_size_h
    resized =  image_src.resize((640, 640))   # To be imblemnated : letterbox_image(image_src, (img_size_w, img_size_h))
    print('After resizing :' ,resized.size, resized.mode) # size order : width*height
    #display(resized)

    # Preprocess the image
    img_in = np.transpose(resized, (2, 0, 1)).astype(np.float32)  # HWC -> CHW
    img_in = np.expand_dims(img_in, axis=0) # Add redundant dimension for batch-size (Assumed to be 1, check batch_size = session.get_inputs()[0].shape[0])
    img_in /= 255.0 # Normalize all pixels
    print('Batch-Size, Channel, Height, Width : ',img_in.shape)
    return img_in
```

What to make changes in the code so that if 2 images are passed they stack together and give shape as (2,3,640,640) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may append the NumPy arrays to a list and convert the list to an array at the end.

- Define your method with variable arguments:

  ```
   def shape(*args):
  ```
- Iterate the arguments, and append the images to a list:

  ```
   imgs_list = []  # List of images (initialize to an empty list)

   for im in args:
       image_src = Image.open(im)

       ...

       imgs_list.append(img_in)  # Append image to list
  ```
- Convert the list to NumPy array, normalize and return the result:

  ```
   imgs_in = np.array(imgs_list)  # Convert the list to NumPy array    
   imgs_in /= 255.0 # Normalize all pixels
   return imgs_in
  ```

---

Updated code of `shape` method:

```
def shape(*args):
    imgs_list = []  # List of images (initialize to an empty list)

    # Iterate all function arguments
    for im in args:
        image_src = Image.open(im)
        print('Loaded Image Info : ',image_src.format, image_src.size, image_src.mode) # size order : width*height

        # Resize to img_size_w, img_size_h
        resized =  image_src.resize((640, 640))   # To be implemented: letterbox_image(image_src, (img_size_w, img_size_h))
        print('After resizing :' ,resized.size, resized.mode) # size order : width*height
        #display(resized)

        # Preprocess the image
        img_in = np.transpose(resized, (2, 0, 1)).astype(np.float32)  # HWC -> CHW

        imgs_list.append(img_in)  # Append image to list


    #img_in = np.expand_dims(img_in, axis=0) # Add redundant dimension for batch-size (Assumed to be 1, check batch_size = session.get_inputs()[0].shape[0])

    imgs_in = np.array(imgs_list)  # Convert the list to NumPy array    

    imgs_in /= 255.0 # Normalize all pixels
    print('Batch-Size, Channel, Height, Width : ',imgs_in.shape)

    return imgs_in
```

Usage:

```
res = shape('image1.png', 'image2.png', 'image3.png')
```

Answer (score 3):

Try [np.concatenate](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html)

```
out = np.concatenate([im1, im2], axis=0)
```

Comment: can you see the code this is for 1 image which returns the shape as (1,3,64,64) 
How to stack for 2 images. Not able to figure out

Comment: Please rephrase either your comment or question.  It's really hard to understand what you are saying.  To me it seems like you'd just want to run this over both images and then run concatenate, but it sounds like I need clarification

Comment: hope it makes you clear ,yes your understanding is right just want to run this over both images and then run concatenate.
if any clarification needed i will try that